# RISC-V 16 and 32 bits instructions

Tags: riscv

```
c0500100:       0100006f                j       c0500110 <START>
c0500104:       00000013                nop
c0500108:       00000013                nop
c050010c:       00000013                nop

c0500110 <START>:
c0500110:       4605                    li      a2,1
c0500112:       4701                    li      a4,0
```

"li" use 16 bits instruction, how can I force it to be 32 bits only?

Comment: What compiler, assembler ("toolchain") do you use?

Comment: If you're using gcc, you'll want to look into the `-march=` command line option.  For example, `-march=rv32imac` is a popular choice that includes 32-bit (not 64-bit) processor, along with the multiply, atomic, and compressed extensions.  You want to remove the `c` from that as in `-march=rv32ima`.  Other tools will probably have similar.

Comment: Yes, riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc  (gcc)

Comment: Yes, it is working fine with "-march=rv32i -mabi=ilp32" now, thanks